# Rishonim & Chazal on Bereishit as allegory/metaphorical

Tags: rambam, creation, genesis-bereishith, chazal

I know the Rambam stays Maaseh Bereishit is largely allegory. I wanted to know if there are other Rishonim Geonim and/or Chazal sources that are similar or agreeing with the Rambam.
Sometimes people put aside the Rambam as being a unique opinion and so having other sources in my arsenal(if they exist) would be of value to me.

Thank you community!

Comment: Where is this Rambam?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Eitan and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I think you would find the Gra and Maharal would say this is largely allegorical.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE where? Would like to weigh up the Gra with this:  https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.13. eitan, what do you need these "weapons" for, exactly?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Maybe more precisely the Gra holds *maaseh bereishis* is a mix and confluence of all the *olamos*, e.g. http://yosefavivi.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_08.html תלמידו של הגר"א, ר' משה שלמה מטולטשין, הזכיר במפורש את הסדר הזה: ספר, סיפור וספר. "עוד שמעתי מהרב המחבר שאמר לי פא"פ בספר וסיפור וספר, כי הבריאה היה צריך מחשבה דבור ומעשה. וז"ש בראשית הוא מחשבה, ואח"כ ויאמר הוא סיפור, ואח"כ ויהי הוא מעשה, ואח"כ וירא אלהים כי טוב, פירוש שראה שאינו חסר כלום כ"א כולו במילואו וטובו, וזש"ה אז ראה ויספרה הכינה וגם חקרה. וכן בספר תורה צריך ספר ממה לכתוב ואח"כ לומר בפיו ואח"כ לכתוב ואח"כ לראות ולהגיה